# Understanding about "close up"

Tags: interpretation

> We could see him close up. (An example sentence from my workbook without context)

We have a debate about whether this sentence should be understood as we had a close look at him or  We could see him coming this way. We need your help to determine which understanding is correct.

Comment: Not 'coming this way', just that he was near you at the time you saw him.

Comment: @KateBunting Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Close-up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/close-up) means **at close range**.  It does not have any added meaning referring to movement.

> close-up
> 2 of 2
> adverb or adjective
> ˌklōs-ˈəp
> : at close range